# ReactJS - How to implement a callback function from JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-props, react-state

I am having a question about how to implement a callback function. In my case, I have a React app with this structure: **App** > **Child** > **Button** components

The problem is I do not know how to write a callback function from **Button** to **Child**

I would like to update a value in Child (e.g: inputFromButton) after clicking the button in Button Component. The handleClick() is triggered and a value will be sent to the Child component.
Could someone help me to do this?

Here is my code:https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-stonebraker-0950w8
The App component

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from './Child';
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: 'Data from App'
    }
  }

  handleCallback = (childData) => {
    this.setState({ data: childData })
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Child dataFromApp={data} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

The Child component

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderButton } from './Button';
class Child extends React.Component {
    state = {
        inputFromApp: "",
        inputFromButton: ""
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            inputFromApp: this.props.dataFromApp
        })
    }
    render() {
        const renderButtonItem = renderButton(this.props);
        const inputFromApp = this.state.inputFromApp
        const inputFromButton= this.state.inputFromButton
        return (
            <div>
                <input value={inputFromApp}></input>
                <br></br>
                <input value={inputFromButton}></input>
                <div>{renderButtonItem}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Child
```

The Button component

```
import React from 'react';
export const renderButton = (props) => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log('handleClick() props data from App: ' + props.dataFromApp)

    }
    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    )
}
```

Comment: [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `renderButton` is a function *component* and, therefore, needs to be in PascalCase: `RenderButton` (although it would be better off as `Button`).
2. Move `handleClick` to the `Child` component.
3. Then in `Button` the call to `handleClick` should be `props.handleClick` since `handleClick` will now be a property of the `props` object passed into the component. We don't need to pass down the data as a prop to the button but can, instead just log the data prop passed into `Child`.

   ```
   handleClick = () => {
     console.log(`handleClick(): ${props.dataFromApp}`);
   }
   ```
4. In `Child`, instead of calling `renderButton`, import `Button`, and then use that in the render passing down the handler in the props. By doing this you're making the component as "dumb" as possible so it can be reused elsewhere in the application.

   ```
   <Button handleClick={this.handleClick} />
   ```